# Azure Function Publish failed error message

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

When I try to publish my AF (VS 2017 v15.8.6), I get the following error message: "Publishing failed." I downloaded the publishing profile and successfully loaded it in VS. As you can see the Output window is empty. Why is that? I literally do nothing wrong...

[image]

Comment: Have you seen other related messages about this failure on Output?

Comment: The Output is empty. The error message just pops up and thats all.

Comment: I've seen this before. In the end the fix for me was to reconnect my Azure subscriptions in the Cloud Explorer. Somehow the credentials got garbled up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reset the Publishing profile of the Function from the Azure Portal and reconnect manually within the Studio without importing any PublishSettings and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was simply an authorization issue. I realized I was not properly signed into the right account within visual studio. If you bring up Serer Explorer, right click, and click Sign into Azure Subscription. That did the trick for me.